# Java consumer thread to wait for all producer threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a multithreading task with producer-consumer pattern. There could be many producers and one consumer. I use ArrayBlockingQueue as a shared resource.

**run() method in Producer class:**

```
public void run() {
         for (Order order : orderList) {
             try {
                 queue.put(order);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         log.info("{} has placed all orders", Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
```

**run() method in Consumer class:**

```
     public void run() {
         while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
             try {
                 Order order = queue.take();
                 checkOrder(order);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         log.info("All orders has been checked");
     }
```

**main() method:**

```
// creating N producers
         for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCERS_NUM; i++) {
             Producer producer = new Producer(orderQueue, orderList);
             new Thread(producer , "Producer " + i).start();
         }
 
         Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Consumer(orderQueue, limitList), "Consumer");
         consumerThread.start();
         consumerThread.join();

**Printing results **
```

Now I have consumer ending condition when queue is empty. But there could be a moment when queue becomes empty for a moment, but some producer threads are still working. So I need to finish consumer thread only AFTER ALL producer threads are finished (but their count is not known beforehand).

What is the proper way to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a fixed number of producers, I would recommend setting a counter at the start with the number of producers. Each producer decrements the counter when it is finished and the consumer only terminates when it reaches zero. For the counter, you would want to use an [Atomic Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/package-summary.html).

Comment: Why not a CountDownLatch?

Comment: I tried this but it seems to me not very clean cause I need to supply an additional argument (counter) to both producer and consumer. So I wanted to look for a better solution.

Comment: @codeflush.dev I don't think a CountDownLatch is a solution as the consumer wants to make progress whilst the counter is > 0. One could use a CountDownLatch with the getCount instead of await but then that's the same as an Atomic Integer.

Comment: @VitalyKolesnikov whatever you do you will need to have a mechanism for the producer to communicate to the consumer that it has not finished. This will either be part of the already shared state (the queue) or something new. It seems more reasonable to separate the concerns and have this as something separate. I suppose you could extend the queue with this counter to create a CountingQueue or similar where a producer counted up at the start and down at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I should point out that you need to watch out for the race condition where the consumer starts before a producer e.g. you probably want to do the count up in the main thread when you create the producer, not within the producer threads.

Comment: @selig you're right. But you could still use a CDL with `while (!cdl.await(0L, unit))`

Comment: You also have the problem that some producers may finish before other producers even start. If the number of producers is variable then each producer must register with the count-down system, effectively incrementing the count, then de-register with the count-down system which should decrement the count. It is possible to have a set of producers finish before others begin.